# php convert seconds to minutes:seconds only

Tags: php, date, format

I am using this function to convert seconds to minutes:

```
function convert($iSeconds)
{
    return date('i:s', mktime(0, 0, $iSeconds));
}
```

It works great. But if I use this code:

```
echo convert(3605);
```

It returns **00:05**. But I need to return like this: **60:05**

HOW CAN I FORMAT **MINUTES:SECONDS**???

Comment: i'm pretty sure if you change the format to `"H:i:s"` its going to be `1:00:05`. i think you have to manually convert hours to minutes by not using `date` functions.  for example what if yor given is `7210`?

Comment: convert(3605);  here you are inserting miliseconds not seconds if you try convert(600500); then you can see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `mktime()` or `strtotime()` for this kind of conevrsions. You can calculate this manually. You can try this -

```
function convert($iSeconds)
{
   $min = intval($iSeconds / 60);
   return $min . ':' . str_pad(($iSeconds % 60), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}


echo convert(7205);
```

**Output**

```
120:05
```

[Fiddle](https://eval.in/508515)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the date conversion function since it will not accept minutes > 60 and hours > 24.

The easiest way to do it is to use this function:

```
function convert($iSeconds)
{
    $numMinutes = $iSeconds/60;
    $numSeconds = $iSeconds - ($numMinutes * 60);
    $numMinutes = $numMinutes."";
    $numSeconds = $numSeconds."";
    if (strlen($numMinutes) == 1)
        $numMinutes = "0".$numMinutes;
    if (strlen($numSeconds) == 1)
        $numSeconds = "0".$numSeconds;
    return $numMinutes.":".$numSeconds;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of `mktime`, for `minute`:

> The number of the minute relative to the start of the hour. Negative values reference the minute in the previous hour. Values
>   greater than 59 reference the appropriate minute in the following
>   hour(s).

And for `second`:

> The number of seconds relative to the start of the minute. Negative values reference the second in the previous minute. Values
>   greater than 59 reference the appropriate second in the following
>   minute(s).

When you call `mktime` you are passing a value of 0 for both hours and minutes; with 3605 seconds you are basically "spinning" the `seconds` hand on the clock 3600/60 times, and *then* you add those 5 seconds.

So you will have to first manually calculate the correct values for minutes and possibly hours that your given amount of seconds amounts to.

For that, you will need to use `mod` and `intval` of the division.

In a very educational format you'd have something like:

```
function convert($iSeconds) {
  $seconds = $iSeconds % 60;
  $minutes = intval($iSeconds/60);
  $hours = intval($minutes/60);
  $minutes = $minutes % 60;

  return date('H:i:s', mktime($hours, $minutes, $seconds));
}
```

https://eval.in/508531

Indeed, this doesn't directly solve the OP, as the number of minutes can be of arbitrary size. As noted, `mktime` cannot be used to achieve that, as it will always format a "proper" time value, where minutes and seconds are a number between 0-59.